# Relay kept on by near transformer

Tags: switches, relay, electromagnetism, coil

I had a wireless powersocket for my PC peripherals until it stopped working. It just kept closed even if I turned it off and heard clicking. I opened the socket and replaced the board inside with my own relay circuit and the same happened. If I cut power long enough, the relay was opened again, but only until I turned it on.

My question is, if it's possible that the power-supply of my PC-Screen could be the problem, as it was directly behind the socket. It was switched by the relay too and I think the coil in there kept magnetized the coil inside the relay. Is that true?

Comment: Wireless power socket? Sounds like something Tesla would be proud of :-)

Comment: Well yeah, if it was "Wireless power _supply_" :)

Comment: Try a Mu-Metal magnetic shield if you really think magnetism is causing this.

Comment: Not needed, I added a pulldown to my circuit and increased the distance to the power supply a few cm. I just wanted to know if this could be the cause by interest.

Comment: no, the coil needs a lot of current, far more than parasitics would provide. it more likely triggered the drive circuit, which controls the relay from a small signal. This is like how you can get hum from having power run near audio inputs, but nothing from having power near speaker cables.

Comment: thank you, this is the anwer I was awaitng! This means my pull-down was the solution.
If you post your comment as an answer I will mark it as the right one.